# Malfunction css file

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I got my css file which will be under the text but when i try to open the html file that uses it in the browser it doesn't work, the css code won't run and the styling and the javascript don't work because of that. The code is supposed to be like this one: https://codepen.io/ritaD86/pen/MyOdQr but it doesn't work in my browser while it works on the codepen.io. I also don't get it why the javascript doesn't work. What is going on? What can I do?

```js
persons = [
    person = {
      firstName: "Maria",
      lastName: "Fernanda",
      age: "mf@desk.com",
      phone: "917697967"
    },
  ];
  
  document.getElementById('search_button').addEventListener('click', searchPerson);
  document.getElementById('add_button').addEventListener('click', addPerson);
  document.getElementById('show_all').addEventListener('click', showAllPersons);
  
  
  
  
  function searchPerson() {
    var input = document.getElementById("search").value.toLowerCase();
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
  
    for (var i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
  
      if (input === persons[i].firstName.toLowerCase() || input === persons[i].lastName.toLowerCase()) {
        result.innerHTML = '<h4>I found this:</h4>' + persons[i].firstName + ' ' +
          persons[i].lastName + ' </br>' + persons[i].age + ' </br>' + persons[i].phone;
        return persons[i];
  
      } else if (!isNaN(input)) {
        result.innerHTML = 'Tem de inserir um nome';
      } else {
        result.innerHTML = 'Nenhum contacto encontrado';
      }
    }
  }
  
  function Person(first, last, age, phone) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.phone = phone;
  }
  
  function titleCase(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
  }
  
  function addPerson() {
    var firstName = titleCase(document.getElementById("name").value);
    var lastName = titleCase(document.getElementById("lastname").value);
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  
    var newPerson = new Person(firstName, lastName, age, phone);
    persons.push(newPerson);
  
    if (newPerson.firstName != undefined) {
      alert(newPerson.firstName + ' added');
    } else {
      alert('No person added');
    }
    
    showAllPersons();
  }
  
  function showAllPersons() {
    var i;
    var l;
    var showButton = document.getElementById('show_all');
    var list = document.getElementById('all_list');
    
    while (list.firstChild) {
      list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
    }
    
    
    for (var l = 0; l < persons.length; l++) {
      var node = document.createElement("LI");
      list.appendChild(node);
      node.innerHTML =
        '<p><b>Nome Completo:</b> ' + persons[l].firstName +' ' + persons[l].lastName + '</p>' +
        '<p><b>Email:</b> ' + persons[l].age + '</p>' +
        '<p><b>Telemovel:</b> ' + persons[l].phone + '</p>'
  
      for (var key in person) {
        var value = person[key];
      }
    }
    showButton.disabled = true;
  }
```

```css
@import "bourbon";
@import "neat";

// Media queries
$desktop: new-breakpoint(min-width 960px 12);
$tablet: new-breakpoint(max-width 959px 12);
$mobile: new-breakpoint(max-width 767px 4);

// Variables
$max-width: 1200px;

form {
  padding: 20px 0 40px;
  
  .field {
    @include padding(10px 0);
    @include margin(5px 0);
    @include display(inline-block);
    @include fill-parent;
    
    label {
      @include span-columns(5);
      @include padding(5px 10px);
    }
    
    input {
      @include span-columns(7);
      @include padding(5px 10px);
    }
  }
}

.container {
  @include outer-container;
  text-align: center;
}

.search_person {
  @include span-columns(6);
}

.add_person {
  @include span-columns(6);
}

.all_persons {
  @include span-columns(4);
  @include shift(4);
  
  #all_list {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
    
    li {
      margin: 0 0 30px;
      text-align: left;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Desk+ - Grupo 36</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ab.css">
        <script src="ab.js"></script>
        </head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Contactos</h1>
    
    <div class="all_persons">
      <button id="show_all" type="button">Mostrar todos</button>
      <ul id="all_list">
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="search_person">
      <h3>Insira um nome</h3>
      <input type="text" id="search">
      <button id="search_button" type="button">Procurar</button>
      <p id="result"></p>
    </div>
  
   <div class="add_person">
     <h3>Adicionar contacto</h3>
      <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="field">
          <label for="firstname">Primeiro Nome: </label>
          <input type="text" id="name">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label for="lastname">Último Nome: </label>
          <input type="text" id="lastname">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label for="age">Email: </label>
          <input type="text" id="age">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label for="phone">Phone: </label>
          <input type="number" id="phone">
        </div>
        <button id="add_button" type="button">Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the css you've posted is written in sass/scss/less, whereas the browser can only compile css. Your code needs to be pre-compiled before the browser can render it; codepen does that behind the scene.

Comment: Oh ok. So is there any way of transforming the sacss/scss/less into css?

Comment: If you need this job done just for this gig, see the compiled css in the answer below. If you need it to be done often but not always, try to look for online compilers, where they can compile the code you paste in.
If you are looking for a consistent way to compile sass/scss/less try to look into npm packages that might compile the code. There are plenty.  Feel free to ask more specific questions for more specific answers :)

Comment: Already did that. Using free compilers online thanks man @Adriano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the compiled css->

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

form {
  padding: 20px 0 40px;
}
form .field {
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
form .field label {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.3576520234%;
  width: 40.291369653%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
form .field label:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
form .field input {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.3576520234%;
  width: 57.3509783236%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
form .field input:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.container::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.search_person {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.3576520234%;
  width: 48.8211739883%;
}
.search_person:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.add_person {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.3576520234%;
  width: 48.8211739883%;
}
.add_person:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.all_persons {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 2.3576520234%;
  width: 31.7615653177%;
  margin-left: 34.1192173411%;
}
.all_persons:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.all_persons #all_list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.all_persons #all_list li {
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

try this instead the css/scss you are using. It will work. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It is SCSS and not CSS. You need to convert it to CSS first for it to work. In addition to that, try to move your script to the end of the body tag instead of inside the head tag.